# How to set compatibility level in PDFLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, pdf

normally pdflatex produces pdf compatible with acrobat reader 6.0 and later right? How do I make it compatible only with version 9.0 forward acrobat reader?

I use TeXLive 2011

Comment: Why would you want that? You should add some more detail to your question.

Comment: Maybe the question should be rephrased to something more general, like 'How to set compatibility level?'.

Comment: what details do you need?

Comment: @FormlessCloud: An explanation of why you want to make your documents compatible with new versions of Acrobat only. Are you trying to make use of a particular feature only available with newer versions of Acrobat?

Comment: right! in particular I'm trying to set the protection of pdf with 256-bit algorithm, which is only supported from version 9.0 forward...

Comment: @FormlessCloud: How do you activate that protection? Using Adobe Acrobat Professional (or something like that)? Can't you use the same program you use for setting the protection to also set the version compatibility?

Comment: In fact, modifying the PDF created with pdflatex using the algorithm to 256 bits after saving it from error

Comment: yes i'm using acrobat professional... i think that the compatibility of pdf need to be modified when you make it or no?

Comment: @FormlessCloud: I think if you select the compatibility version in the "Password Security" options, that will also change the compatibility version of your document.

Comment: http://it.comp.software.tex.narkive.com/s2PvK70O/livello-di-compatibilita-pdf

see this. i can't make it for pdflatex with texlive 2011?

Comment: i need compatibility 1.8

Comment: @FormlessCloud: That document is from five years ago. What version of Acrobat Professional are you using?

Comment: my version is X v10

Comment: @FormlessCloud: I'm pretty sure you that with Acrobat X all you need to do is choose the compatibility level in the "Password Security - Settings" screen. Have you tried that?

Comment: Will putting  `\pdfminorversion=8` in preamble be useful?. But it is better if you use xetex or luatex.

Comment: [XY](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2450/5763): What's the problem you want to solve?

Comment: My problem is about consistence. My university officer gave me a PDF 2.0 doc to be included in my thesis, so I have to do that... Eventually, I asked them to transfer the doc to another version. So, it's a rare case, but might come to others.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only set `\pdfminorversion=7` to force the version to PDF 1.7 - there is no newer version of PDF yet (the current ISO norm standardized PDF 1.7; the next revision of the norm will probably be called PDF 2.0). Note that this only sets the *version number of the PDF*: There is no other difference in the PDF produced by pdfTeX to that with `\pdfminorversion=5` or `6`.

If you want to make your document *claim* to conform to the ExtensionLevels specified [by newer version of Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html), you can probably do this with `\pdfliteral`.

Comment: Given that PDF 2.0 has been published, is now generating PDF 2.0 document available using pdflatex? I haven't seen this feature mentioned in the pdflatex manual, but I may have missed something.

Comment: @XiaodongQi: AFAIK no. And since the PDF 1.x references explicitly say that a change in the major PDF version (e.g. from 1.x to 2.x) may change *everything*, I doubt that most viewers will accept 2.0 documents now. But that's a different question.

Comment: @XiaodongQi Does `luatex` support creation of `pdf 2.0` files? Which readers shall support them?

Comment: I haven't checked luatex recently, by the time, not to my knowledge. My problem is about consistence. A university officer gave me a PDF 2.0 doc to be included into my thesis, so I have to do that... Eventually, I asked them to transfer the doc to another version. But cases like that might happen to other people.