# How to generate PDF 2.0 output using pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, pdf

Based on the [manual of PDFLaTeX](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf), it seems `pdflatex` can support generating pdf up to version 1.7 (ISO 32000-1:2008) using `\pdfminorversion=7`. To use PDF 2.0 (ISO 32000-2:2017), can I define a major version number =2 alongside with `\pdfminorversion=0` or something like that?

Comment: Painting red a 50 year old Fiat 500 doesn't make it into a Ferrari. `:-)` Not that `pdftex` should be compared to a 50 year old Fiat 500, but it doesn't support the new features in PDF 2.0, yet.

Comment: See my comment at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60186/5763

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you have any software that *needs* PDF 2.0?

Comment: @MartinSchröder I actually have to include a PDF 2.0 figure into my tex given by others. But when I compile in a normal way, it always complains the compiler can only support PDF up to v1.7/1.6 or something like that. After searching around, the solution seems to be updating pdf version number to 2.0 for the compiling.

Comment: @XiaodongQi: You have a PDF 2.0 figure? How did you produce that?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Can `LuaTeX` produce `2.0` output?

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a PDF document that claims to conform to the PDF 2.0 specification using luatex (tested with version 1.10.0) as follows:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\directlua {   
  pdf.setmajorversion(2)   
  pdf.setminorversion(0) 
} 
Foo. 
\end{document}
```

On this simple example, the output does seem compatible with the standard, at least according to [the pdf-tools online validator](http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx). That won't necessarily be the case for more complex documents, even if the 2.0 specification has been designed as much as possible as a superset of previous versions, to allow graceful degradation for software that has been developed for older versions of the standard.

Answer (score 2):

At present the answer is no for pdfTeX, but plans for TeX Live 2020 work are already in place and I (and others) will look to add a new primitive to support this (likely `\pdfmajorversion`). The main issue is not the primitive itself but the supporting 'environment': there are lots of places that test for the minor version as a boundary/cut off for different features, and picking up that 2.0 > 1.4 is going to be fun!

Comment: `plans for TeX Live 2020 work are already in place` -> How did it go?